# Facebook SDK returning data but for loop needs to be limited to only 5 posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, sdk

I've built a small test that uses the Facebook JS SDK to pull public posts from a public page and display them on a webpage. My problem is that it works sometimes, but other times only the dom is populated with the information and nothing shows up on the page. You can see a live version here: http://realbadrabbits.com/test/fb.html

If you look in the console you will see that the AJAX call is successfully returning the post IDs (which I am inserting into DIVs and appending to the #app div). I think the problem is that it's taking about 6 seconds on my connection to collect all the content. If this is the case how would I edit this code to limit the responses to only the first 5 posts?

```
for (x in res.feed.data) { // code that builds the DIV's};
```

Adblock plugins also seem to be a problem, so I've turned them all off :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Increment a counter variable inside the for loop, and then break out of the loop when it reaches 5.

Comment: Simple and oh so obvious. Thanks @CBroe :)